# 500 error post from another web site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post

I do POST request for a external site. The site returns me data, also the POST method. I have no access to an external site (it is bank). Also there is a test page, for check that action of the controler works.

The problem in that when I do POST from test page all works fine: external site recieve my POST and send me results back (action of controller is works), but when I do POST to external site, it's recieve my POST, but I can't recieve POST from bank.

This is IIS log( first line from bank, second from test page):

```
2012-04-02 08:00:11 82.200.165.5 POST /Home/PostLinkTest - 80 - 193.93.56.223 Java/1.6.0_31 500 0 0 31

2012-04-02 08:01:58 82.200.165.5 POST /Home/PostLinkTest - 80 - 2.133.42.201 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:11.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/11.0 200 0 0 227
```

**UPDATE:**
 This is action:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult PostLinkTest()
        {

            StreamWriter erFile = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~"), "\\error\\error.txt"), true);

            string strTimeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm");
            erFile.WriteLine("Date " + strTimeStamp);
            erFile.WriteLine("------------------------");
            erFile.WriteLine("PostLinkTest ");
            erFile.WriteLine("------------------------ X -------------------------");
            erFile.Close();   

            return View("ShowResponse");

        }
```

**UPDATE 2:**:  trying to catch error:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           var error = Server.GetLastError();
           StreamWriter erFile = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~"), "\\error\\error.txt"), true);

           string strTimeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm");
           erFile.WriteLine("Date " + strTimeStamp);
           erFile.WriteLine("------------------------");
           erFile.WriteLine("ApplicationError: " + error.Message + "\n" + error.StackTrace);
           erFile.WriteLine("------------------------ X -------------------------");
           erFile.Close();
        }
```

**UPDATE 3:**
I enabled tracing and the results is the following. This is screenshot:
[image]
Thanks.
PS. Version of IIS 7.5.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided any details about how your site works we can only be guessing here. So here's my guess: your controller action depends on some Session or something user specific and when you created a sample page to test the POST request and executed it in the web browser it worked because you performed it from the context of the current user, but when the external web site performed a POST request to your action it failed because it was not associated to any user (it didn't send the session cookie) and your controller action crashed when you attempted to access the data. So put some logging in your controller action and see how the request from the external web site differs than the request you manually crafted.

Comment: Thanks. Action is pretty simple (write in file the some text). I updated my question.

Comment: Try making it even simpler to see if it works: `[HttpPost] public ActionResult PostLinkTest() { return Content(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm")); }`. Also do you have some custom action filters (global or not) that might be executing? Look at the Event Log of your server. When an unhandled exception is thrown in ASP.NET it will be traced there. So in the event of HTTP 500 status code you probably will get more details about the error in the Event Log of your web server.

Comment: I tried this, but results the same. No, I don't have any action filters

Comment: OK, so what do you see in the Event Log? What's the exception causing this 500 error? Another possibility is for you to subscribe to the `Application_Error` callback in Global.asax and trace the error. 500 HTTP status code is most probably caused by some exception in your application that you must try to log.

Comment: In the Event Log nothing error. I now will try `Application_Error` and report about result.

Comment: Darin: See updated question please. In the file no records (file is exist, and other action write info into this file, here is all okay).

Comment: I simulated error and `Application_Error` catch it. But POST from external site does not catch.